# Script doesn't load within folder only external

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bookmarks

```
<div><a id=link_style
        href="javascript:(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='http://website.com/info/scripts/main-min.js';})();"
        style="color: black;">
    <div id="drag-with-image" class="some-div" style="position:absolute;z-index:999;" draggable="true">
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm having this code in my html script, which loads a main-min.js which is published external on a http://website.com/info/scripts/main-min.js this works but what I would love to have is that it actually loads within my scripts folder the .js file which I tried this for:

```
<div><a id=link_style
        href="javascript:(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='scripts/main-min.js';})();"
        style="color: black;">
    <div id="drag-with-image" class="some-div" style="position:absolute;z-index:999;" draggable="true">
    </div>
</div>
```

What can I do to have this, what am I doing wrong, is this even possible?

Comment: Have you tried to put `http://localhost:port/..../scripts/main-min.js`??

Comment: Does the file exist in your scripts folder? If not, you have to put it there, or tell the server that any request for that file should redirect to the external one.

Comment: @EleazarEnrique didn't try that yet, right away going to try it.

Comment: @stratedge Yes, the script is in my scripts folder, with my code I did do it to an external one, which works, but I want to work with it directly (as in scripts/main-min.js) and not having to re-upload my main-min.js file the whole time to see if it works.

Comment: Only other thing that would be worth confirming I think is the path to the scripts directory relative to the path of the document you are viewing - if the document you are viewing is in the same directory as the scripts directory, I would expect this to work. If the scripts directory is in your root, for example, and this file is in a different directory, the path to the script would need to be adjusted.

Comment: @EleazarEnrique Totally worked out for now, will work tomorrow morning further on it so I'll keep heads up! I think this is the best solution for me at the moment!